# Trying to access an apache site takes me to index of/ instead of directly to the page

Tags: apache2

I have a html file (named `stran1.html`) in `/var/www/public_html/stran1/`, and a virtual host with `ServerName` set as my domain and `DocumentRoot` set as the previously mentioned path.

I am using `afraid DNS` to forward the domain to my IP.

This all works, except when i try to access the site from a web browser i get a `index of /` page.

I can then click on `stran1.html` to get taken to the page i want.

Typing in my IP takes me to the default page as it should.

Edit: I found something weird.

If i delete the default `index.html` in `/var/www/html` and replace it with another html file (in my example `test.html`) then typing the ip into the browser also takes me to an `index of /` page, that includes a link to `test.html`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the default and expected behaviour of Apache. When given a URI that points to a directory, it will try to show one of the files listed in the [`DirectoryIndex`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) setting, or if none of those files are found, show a file listing. The default `DirectoryIndex`uses various `index.*` files (`index.html` at least, `index.php` if you have  PHP installed, etc.). If you want to use a different file by default, you'll have to use a `.htaccess` file, or a `Directory` block in the appropriate `VirtualHost`, and set `DirectoryIndex` to the desired file name.

Comment: I added a DirectoryIndex into the right VirutalHost .conf file and now it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting DocumentRoot to `/var/www/public_html/stran1/stran1.html`.

Comment: Tried it and it now gives me a not found error. Setting it back is sending me to index of/ again.